# Git stash and reset not working as expected

Tags: git, git-stash, git-reset

I have unstaged changes (in tracked files) that I want to delete. I try running `git stash` then `git stash drop`, and the unstaged changes are still there. I try running `git add -A` and then `git reset --hard` but `git status` still shows the files as having unstaged, uncommitted changes!! What is wrong with git?

Furthermore, when I do a `git status` after `git stash -A`, there are still unstaged changes!! I really want to pop something off my stash stack but git is preventing me because there are unstaged changes that will conflict, but git also won't let me delete those changes.

Comment: If `git reset --hard` still leaves you with "unstaged changes", that nearly always means there are end-of-line issues. They must be cleaned up first (which usually means adding a new commit that cleans them up).

Comment: I can't commit the changes, it doesn't let me add them in the first place.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Actual commands and their results might help (see [mcve]).